# The impact of the class size on performance of the member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I found that the executation time of member function in class is affected by the class size when traversing an array of objects.  I am wondering why this happended and is there any possibility to improve the speed?

The real problem I encountered involved a complex class with multi-level inheritance and virtual function. The different class size (e.g. 5x class size to 2x more time cost) will lead to a remarkable time consumption. A simple test code and the result is shown as follows:

```
using namespace std;
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
class Base {
public:
    virtual void Compute()=0;
};
class A: public Base{
public:
    char a[1000];
    virtual void Compute(){
        int c = 100;
        c *= 100;
    }
};

class B: public Base{
public: 
    char a[3000];
    virtual void Compute(){
        int c = 100;
        c *= 100;
    }
};

void TestClassMemory(){
    int N = 20000;
    A* pA = new A[N];
    B* pB = new B[N];
    int Nloop = 1000;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i<Nloop; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){
            pA[j].Compute();
        }

    }
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    double dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << "A time cost: " << dt;

    t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i<Nloop; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){
            pB[j].Compute();
        }
    }
    t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << " B time cost: " << dt << std::endl;
    // t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(t2 - t1).count();
    // std::cout << "C time cost: " << dt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size A: " << sizeof(A) << " size B: " << sizeof(B) << std::endl;
    delete [] pA;
    delete [] pB;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TestClassMemory();
}
```

The expection of the code should have the same time cost while the result shows some unexpectation.

```
A time cost: 0.0429354 B time cost: 0.0652356
size A: 1008 size B: 3008
```

Comment: Cache misses increase with element size of an array.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why are you measuring this?

Comment: If compiled with optimizations, the loops would be optimized out because they have no side effects. And there is not much point in testing this without optimizations.

Comment: You can see that in action here: https://godbolt.org/z/ZHE2U2 (The code lines that not colored have been removed because they have no effect). You are basically measuring how fast the program can call steady_clock::now()

Comment: You can make the `c` variable `volatile` to prevent this optimization. You should then see comparable results in the two cases.

Comment: @Timbo You are right. I made a mistake. I have changed the test code as similar to my real problem as possible. The virtual function really slows down the performance and differrent class size truely leads to differrent call time.

Comment: @TuanDT To seek the possibility to make the code perform more efficiently.

Comment: @zskalibur I see. I don't have the full story, but usually if you go down this path, just make sure that you really really really need it. Most of the time, the most critical part of optimization is identify the bottle neck `using a profiler`.

Comment: @TuanDT Thanks for your advice. I will try it.